# Is it possible to show the ordered items and shipping method on the success page?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, order-success-page

I wanna customize the success page because is very poor of information, so I would like to bring on page the order status, ordered items table, shipping address and shipping method details, like here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/media/catalog/product/cache/9/image/725x680/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/r/fr_1.png

Additionally, I've heard that some things changed on the magento 1.9 core, so, how to break session in order to edit CSS and refresh the page without redirects?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this would give you all the details you need for adding order details to `success.pthml`:

```
// Load order details
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$orderDetails = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
zend_debug::dump($orderDetails);
```

---

Edit from comment, for `success.pthml`:

```
<?php
//**********************************Order Details***************************
if($this->getOrderId()):
//echo $this->getOrderId();
//$orderObj = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$orderItems = $orderObj->getAllVisibleItems();
?>
<div><table >
<thead>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Subtotal</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?
$_product = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)->load($items->getProductId());
foreach($orderItems as $items){
$product_small_image_path = Mage::helper(‘catalog/image’)->init($_product, ‘small_image’)->resize(135);
?>
<tr>
<td><span><img src=”<?php echo $product_small_image_path ?>”/></span><? echo $items->getName();?></td>
<?php ?><td><? echo number_format($items->getPrice(),3);?></td><?php
?><td><? echo $items->getQtyOrdered(); ?></td><?php
$totalprice = ($items->getQtyOrdered())*($items->getPrice());
?><td><? echo number_format($totalprice,3); ?></td></tr><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I will take a look at these variables, what are returned etc. But, can't we show those data rendering the orders table Magento uses across the customer account for example?

Comment: https://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/custom-thank-you-page-in-magento-success-phtml/